# CORS issue with Tomcat

Tags: javascript, api, tomcat7, cors

We have a tomcat webserver (server1), which is hosting a couple of webpages containing JavaScripts to call backend APIs hosted on a different webserver (server2).

When I am navigating to the webpages on server1, it is throwing an error -

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at server2/api. (Reason: CORS request failed)."

When I make a call to the api on server2 directly from a POST client, I am able to get a response.

I understand that we have to enable CORS on the server. But which server should we enable the CORS on? Will it be the Tomcat server (server1) which is hosting the webpages, or the API server (server2) which is hosting the APIs?

Additionally we tried enabling CORS on Tomcat by adding the Filters as per http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter
but that did not help.

Please advise.

Regards,
Ritwik

Comment: it will be the API server (server2). It should work if you configure it correctly, but you'll need to provide more information about the setup on server2 for anyone to be able to help you - what is serving your API? Servlets? Any framework? Have you mapped paths correctly? etc.

Comment: you can check  [here](http://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html)

Comment: @CupawnTae, a followup question - why isn't the request even reaching server2 now? I can see the request coming into server1 and return a http304. But I can't even see the request coming into server2 web logs.

Answer (score 1):

CORS needs the recipient of a call to allow or disallow. In your scenario you need server2 to allow connections of server1.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Make sure that your whitelist contains the correct URL, for example `https://server1:8081/`, because all of protocol, host and port need to match !

http://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html

Comment: ya, this is a great resource to help about the CORS.

Comment: @Marged, thank you for the response. I have a question. I am not even seeing the request reach server2. And on server1, I see HTTP 304. Will enabling CORS on server2 ensure that the requests reach server2 and server2 will be able to serve it?

Comment: @Ritwik yes, it will. I have seen browsers that hide the preflight CORS request and it might not show in the logfiles of server2. The safest way to see them is either use the network traces a browser or Wireshark provide.